# How to display calendar Recurrence Data Field (daily, weekly, monthly) in list view?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, spservices

I need help on displaying the recurrence data (Daily,Weekly,etc) field in a list view. I have a calendar event list and in my custom view I need to show the value of the recurrence data in a column. I've already checked the "Recurrence" field in the "Modify View" section but I only see the "circular arrow icon that stands for recurring event" and not the recurrence data. Is this possible in sharepoint 2007?

**Column1    Column2**

sometext      Daily

sometext      Weekly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box due to the value provided by the 'Recurrence' field is not sufficient for your requirement.

There is however a long blog post on how to use SPServices to [get recurring events as distinct items](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Use-SPServices-to-Get-Recurring-Events-as-Distinct-Items.aspx). There were a couple of items covered including how some date ranges when querying do not work as expected but he provides a way around those items.

With the information of each item's recurrence provided you can create another method to filter them if they are on a daily, weekly or monthly recurrence prior to displaying them on a customized page.